# Retrieve substring from given string

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is related to login. This answer may be simple but still 30 mins I am trying using jquery OR javascript.

Given string Example :

`john123,ricky43567,jecobs2` and many more like this

Retrieve only character from it.

above string result will be like..

```
john,ricky,jecobs
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are substr and substring methods in JavaScript

Comment: So do you want to retrieve only the letters?

Comment: What to do with strings like: `jonh@@$$123`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a regex

```
[^a-z,]
```

So it would be:

```
var str = 'john123,ricky43567,jecobs2';

var result = str.replace(/[^a-z,]/ig, '')
```

### [Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?34tdl)

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJZvt/)

Answer (score 2):

Try a regex like, have look at [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```
var x = 'john123,ricky43567,jecobs2'.replace(/[^a-z,]/ig, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = 'john123,ricky43567,jecobs2';
str = str.replace(/\d/g,'');
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/zYfWc/2/

Output `-->` `john,ricky,jecobs`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var str = 'john123,ricky43567,jecobs2';
  myString = str.replace(/(\d+)/g,'');
   alert(myString);
```